# How to draw shaded circles with specific colors?

Tags: beamer, color, pstricks, circles

I want to draw the circles of this picture:

[image]

But I cannot find the exact colors definition and how to make them shaded as in the picture.

Here is an example of a code I am trying

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}      
 \usecolortheme{beaver} 
 \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=gray!10!white, fg=gray!10!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{bg=darkred}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{pst-coil,pst-slpe}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex]{palette quaternary}%               
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{}{}
   \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }
  }
  \definecolor{blue-green}{rgb}{0.0, 0.87, 0.87}
  \definecolor{electricyellow}{rgb}{1.0, 1.0, 0.0}
  \definecolor{glaucous}{rgb}{0.38, 0.51, 0.71}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
   \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{center}
   \psscalebox{1 1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
      {
       \begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.2)(4.0,-1)
       \pscircle[fillcolor=yellow!20,linecolor=yellow!50, linewidth=0.04,fillstyle=solid](2.0,0.8){0.4}
        \pscircle[fillcolor=blue-green!20,linecolor=blue-green!50, linewidth=0.04,fillstyle=solid](0.4,-0.8){0.4}
        \pscircle[fillcolor=blue!20,linecolor=blue!50, linewidth=0.04,fillstyle=solid](3.6,-0.8){0.4} linewidth=0.04,fillstyle=solid](3.6,-0.8){0.4}
        \psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](2.0,0.4)(0.8,-0.8)
        \psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04](2.0,0.4)(2.0,0.4)(3.2,-0.8)
         \rput[bl](1.78,0.54){\psscalebox{1.4 1.4}{1}}
         \rput[bl](0.2,-1){\psscalebox{1.4 1.4}{2}}
          \rput[bl](3.35,-1){\psscalebox{1.4 1.4}{3}}
          \end{pspicture}
             }
       \caption{\scriptsize Graphe.}
        \end{center}
        \end{figure}
        \end{frame}
        \end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anyway, you should show to us, what you try so far.

Comment: Colors seem to be `#20AD90` (`rgb(32, 173, 144)`) and `#E7D322` (`rgb(231, 211, 34)`) at the borders.

Comment: @Zarko I added an example of a code I am using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-slpe,multido,pst-blur}
\def\Symbol(#1)#2#3{%
    \psBall[shadow,blur](#1){#2!70}{0.3}%
    \pscircle[linecolor=#2](#1){0.3}
    \rput(#1){\scriptsize#3}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-0.5)(4,5)
\multido{\iA=0+1}{5}{%
  \psline[linecolor=black!20](0,\iA)(4,\iA)
  \psline[linecolor=black!20](\iA,0)(\iA,4)}
\Symbol(0,4){yellow}{1}\Symbol(1,4){green}{2}\Symbol(2,4){yellow}{3}
\Symbol(0,3){blue}{3}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For fun. Since I'm not specialist for colors, i select simple colors: yellow and cyan to demonstrate differences in their appearing of they used ass fill or as ball fading:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, chains, positioning, shadings, shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 20mm, on grid,
start chain = A going right,
  Ball/.style = {circle, minimum size=7mm,
                 ball color=#1!50,
                 drop shadow={shadow xshift=2pt, shadow yshift=-2pt,
                              fill=black, 
                              path fading={circle with fuzzy edge 10 percent}},
                 on chain=A
                 },
  Circ/.style = {circle, minimum size=7mm,
                 draw=#1!80!black, very thick, fill=#1!30,
                 drop shadow={shadow xshift=2pt, shadow yshift=-2pt,
                              fill=black,
                              path fading={circle with fuzzy edge 10 percent}},
                 on chain=A
                 }
                        ]
\node[Ball=yellow] {1};                    
\node[Ball=cyan]  {2};
\node[Ball=cyan]  {2};
\node[Ball=yellow] {1};
\node[Ball=cyan,below=of A-1] {2};
\node[Ball=yellow] {1};
\node[Ball=yellow] {1};
\node[Ball=cyan]  {2};
\node[Ball=cyan,below=of A-5] {2};
\node[Ball=yellow] {1};
\node[Ball=cyan]  {2};
\node[Ball=yellow] {1};
\node[Ball=yellow,below=of A-9] {2};
\node[Ball=cyan]  {2};
\node[Ball=yellow] {1};
\node[Ball=cyan]  {2};
\scoped[on background layer] \draw[thick, gray] (A-1) grid[step=20mm] (A-16);
%
\node[Circ=yellow, right=of A-4] {1};
\node[Circ=cyan]  {2};
\node[Circ=cyan]  {2};
\node[Circ=yellow] {1};
\node[Circ=cyan,below=of A-17] {2};
\node[Circ=yellow] {1};
\node[Circ=yellow] {1};
\node[Circ=cyan]  {2};
\node[Circ=cyan,below=of A-21] {2};
\node[Circ=yellow] {1};
\node[Circ=cyan]  {2};
\node[Circ=yellow] {1};
\node[Circ=yellow,below=of A-25] {2};
\node[Circ=cyan]  {2};
\node[Circ=yellow] {1};
\node[Circ=cyan]  {2};
\scoped[on background layer] \draw[thick, gray] (A-17) grid[step=20mm] (A-32);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

When I first viewed the question, there was no example code, so I went to solve the problem in tikz instead of pstricks. I don't know, if this is desired, but I'll attach my solution anyway.

I used the colors found by [epR8GaYuh](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/97168/epr8gayuh). You will need to load special libraries as shown.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{blue-green}{RGB}{32, 173, 144}
    \definecolor{electricyellow}{RGB}{231, 211, 34}

    \node[shape=circle, minimum width=1cm, shading=ball, ball color=electricyellow, circular drop shadow, draw=electricyellow!50!black, thick] (x1_y1) at (0, 0) {1};

    \node[shape=circle, minimum width=1cm, shading=ball, ball color=blue-green, circular drop shadow, draw=blue-green!50!black, thick] (x1_y2) at (0, -2) {2};
    \node[shape=circle, minimum width=1cm, shading=ball, ball color=blue-green, circular drop shadow, draw=blue-green!50!black, thick] (x2_y1) at (2, 0) {2};

    % draw lines between nodes
    \draw (x1_y1) -- (x1_y2);
    \draw (x1_y1) -- (x2_y1);

    % extend the boundng box to not cut the shadows
    \path (x2_y1) -- ++(1, 0);
    \path (x1_y2) -- ++(0, -1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result of this is shown in the following picture. It should be rather straight forward to extend this for the complete grid, either manually or using `foreach` loops introduced by pgf ([manual 3.0.1a on page 901](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=de)).

If the shading inside the circles is not as desired, you can also read the corresponding section on tikz `shadings` library.

You can also load the `positioning` library, and position the nodes relative to each other, but I assume this would not help much further than a well done `foreach`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But I want that they look just like the picture, i.e. I dont want them to look like balls. I updated my code in the question, but the result stil not like the picture.

Comment: Well, I see balls in your picture ;).
Anyhow, you alternative would be to use `shading=radial` if you want any shading at all, our just to use `fill=<color>` instead of shading to ignore the color gradient in the node.